# QEMU boot from a VHDX Virtual Disk in QEMU

Tags: windows-10, boot, virtualization, qemu

Can I use a VHDX and boot from it in QEMU...
or must I convert the image to QCOW?
(using QEmu 5.1 and Windows 10 x64)

*? and can I mount the Virtual-Disk in windows and direct QEMU to it

*? or can I use the QEMU-NBD to expose the block device to a network
for remote use in Hyper-V

Comment: As I only know how to create VHD files without Hyper-V I use VHD file to boot Windows in QEMU.